# Fill dates on dataframe within groups with same ending

Tags: python, pandas, date, pandas-resample

This is what I have:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'item': [1,1,2,2,1,1],
                   'shop': ['A','A','A','A','B','B'],
                   'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018.01.'+ str(x) for x in [2,3,1,4,4,5]]),
                   'qty': [5,6,7,8,9,10]})
print(df)

   item shop       date  qty
0     1    A 2018-01-02    5
1     1    A 2018-01-03    6
2     2    A 2018-01-01    7
3     2    A 2018-01-04    8
4     1    B 2018-01-04    9
5     1    B 2018-01-05   10
```

This is what I want:

```py
out = pd.DataFrame({'item': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1],
                   'shop': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B'],
                   'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018.01.'+ str(x) for x in [2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,4,5]]),
                   'qty': [5,6,0,0,7,0,0,8,0,9,10]})
print(out)

    item shop       date  qty
0      1    A 2018-01-02    5
1      1    A 2018-01-03    6
2      1    A 2018-01-04    0
3      1    A 2018-01-05    0
4      2    A 2018-01-01    7
5      2    A 2018-01-02    0
6      2    A 2018-01-03    0
7      2    A 2018-01-04    8
8      2    A 2018-01-05    0
9      1    B 2018-01-04    9
10     1    B 2018-01-05   10
```

This is what I achieved so far:

```py
df.set_index('date').groupby(['item', 'shop']).resample("D")['qty'].sum().reset_index(name='qty')

   item shop       date  qty
0     1    A 2018-01-02    5
1     1    A 2018-01-03    6
2     1    B 2018-01-04    9
3     1    B 2018-01-05   10
4     2    A 2018-01-01    7
5     2    A 2018-01-02    0
6     2    A 2018-01-03    0
7     2    A 2018-01-04    8
```

I want to complete the missing dates (by day!) so that each group [item-shop] will end with the same date.

Ideas?

Comment: Why `1  A` finally generate `2018-01-02` - `2018-01-05`?

Comment: It doesn’t. Line 2 and 3 are related to shop B.

Comment: Ciao Edo, is it not clear to me which kind of solution are you looking for. Do you mind to Edit your question with the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is the `out` dataframe. I also wrote my expectations (last line) compared to the result I achieved so far (the third dataframe). What kind of information do you think is still missing? I think I’m missing the point of your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is create the `min` and `max` within different group , then we create the range and `explode` `merge` back

```
# find the min date for each shop under each item
s = df.groupby(['item','shop'])[['date']].min()
# find the global max
s['datemax'] = df['date'].max()
# combine two results 
s['date'] = [pd.date_range(x,y) for x , y in zip(s['date'],s['datemax'])]
out = s.explode('date').reset_index().merge(df,how='left').fillna(0)
out

    item shop       date    datemax   qty
0      1    A 2018-01-02 2018-01-05   5.0
1      1    A 2018-01-03 2018-01-05   6.0
2      1    A 2018-01-04 2018-01-05   0.0
3      1    A 2018-01-05 2018-01-05   0.0
4      1    B 2018-01-04 2018-01-05   9.0
5      1    B 2018-01-05 2018-01-05  10.0
6      2    A 2018-01-01 2018-01-05   7.0
7      2    A 2018-01-02 2018-01-05   0.0
8      2    A 2018-01-03 2018-01-05   0.0
9      2    A 2018-01-04 2018-01-05   8.0
10     2    A 2018-01-05 2018-01-05   0.0
```

Comment: "the max here we need the upper universal max for each item". You need a universal max, but **not for each item**. My expected result is the second dataframe, not the third one. The third one it's just an attempt of mine.

Comment: @Edo did you check my output ? try match with your 2nd df firstly

Comment: My second df has 11 rows. Your output has 10. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I think this gives you what you want (columns are ordered differently)

```
max_date = df.date.max()

def reindex_to_max_date(df):
    return df.set_index('date').reindex(pd.date_range(df.date.min(), max_date, name='date'), fill_value=0)

res = df.groupby(['shop', 'item']).apply(reindex_to_max_date)
res = res.qty.reset_index()
```

I grouped by shop, item to give the same sort order as you have in `out` but these can be swapped.

Comment: I liked your answer. Upvoted. The only problem is that with `apply` it makes a lot of copies and it exhausts the RAM pretty fast for big dataframes. Anyhow, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way but one idea is to create a dataframe with all the dates and do a left join at shop-item level as followinf

## Initial data

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'item': [1,1,2,2,1,1],
                   'shop': ['A','A','A','A','B','B'],
                   'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018.01.'+ str(x) 
                                           for x in [2,3,1,4,4,5]]),
                   'qty': [5,6,7,8,9,10]})

df = df.set_index('date')\
       .groupby(['item', 'shop'])\
       .resample("D")['qty']\
       .sum()\
       .reset_index(name='qty')
```

## Dataframe with all dates

We first get the max and min date

```py
rg = df.agg({"date":{"min", "max"}})
```

and then we create a df with all possible dates

```py
df_dates = pd.DataFrame(
    {"date": pd.date_range(
        start=rg["date"]["min"],
        end=rg["date"]["max"])
    })
```

## Complete dates

Now for every shop item we do a left join with all possible dates

```py
def complete_dates(x, df_dates):
    item = x["item"].iloc[0]
    shop = x["shop"].iloc[0]
    x = pd.merge(df_dates, x,
                 on=["date"],
                 how="left")
    x["item"] = item
    x["shop"] = shop
    return x
```

And we finally apply this function to the original `df`.

```py
df.groupby(["item", "shop"])\
  .apply(lambda x: 
         complete_dates(x, df_dates)
        )\
  .reset_index(drop=True)
```

```sh
         date  item shop   qty
0  2018-01-01     1    A   NaN
1  2018-01-02     1    A   5.0
2  2018-01-03     1    A   6.0
3  2018-01-04     1    A   NaN
4  2018-01-05     1    A   NaN
5  2018-01-01     1    B   NaN
6  2018-01-02     1    B   NaN
7  2018-01-03     1    B   NaN
8  2018-01-04     1    B   9.0
9  2018-01-05     1    B  10.0
10 2018-01-01     2    A   7.0
11 2018-01-02     2    A   0.0
12 2018-01-03     2    A   0.0
13 2018-01-04     2    A   8.0
14 2018-01-05     2    A   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to expose the missing values; the end date is the max of `date`, the starting date varies per group of `item` and `shop`.

Create a dictionary that pairs the target column `date` to a new date range:

```
new_date = {"date" : lambda date: pd.date_range(date.min(), df['date'].max())}
```

Pass the `new_date` variable to [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) :

```
# pip install https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import janitor
import pandas as pd

df.complete([new_date], by = ['item', 'shop']).fillna(0)

    item shop       date   qty
0      1    A 2018-01-02   5.0
1      1    A 2018-01-03   6.0
2      1    A 2018-01-04   0.0
3      1    A 2018-01-05   0.0
4      1    B 2018-01-04   9.0
5      1    B 2018-01-05  10.0
6      2    A 2018-01-01   7.0
7      2    A 2018-01-02   0.0
8      2    A 2018-01-03   0.0
9      2    A 2018-01-04   8.0
10     2    A 2018-01-05   0.0
```

[complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) is just an abstraction of pandas functions that makes it easier to explicitly expose missing values in a Pandas dataframe.